# Can we add LWC on external site in salesforce? So that user can access the web form without login? If Yes How?

Tags: lightning-web-components, site.com

I know Right now we can add visualforce pages directly on Sites. Like VF pages can we add LWC component directly on sites. How can we add?

Answer (score 1):

You can expose an `aura:application` in a **Salesforce Site** using `ltng:allowGuestAccess` via Visualforce page. Inside the `aura:application` you can use embed your LWC Component. Please read the official documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ltng:allowGuestAccess/documentation).

*Aura App*

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" 
    implements="ltng:allowGuestAccess"> 
    <aura:dependency resource="c:storeLocatorMain"/>
</aura:application>
```

*Visualforce Page*

```
<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:locatorApp",    // name of the Lightning app
        function() {                  // Callback once framework and app loaded
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c:storeLocatorMain", // top-level component of your app
                { },                  // attributes to set on the component when created
                "lightningLocator",   // the DOM location to insert the component
                function(cmp) {
                    // callback when component is created and active on the page
                }
            );
        },
        'https://universalcontainers.force.com/ourstores/'  // Experience Cloud site endpoint 
    );
</script>
```

You can find the implementation details in this [blog post](https://niksdeveloper.com/salesforce/access-lwc-without-login-using-lightning-out/).

Comment: Or use an experience site